# Managing selection and state of DIVs as radio button options in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, radio-button, state

I am looking to find the React.js way of achieving a common problem.

I  have five DIVs which will act as radio button options when clicked.

The HTML could look like this:

```
//List of option DIVs which act as radio buttons when clicked
const options = () => (
  <div>
    <div>Option 1</div>
    <div>Option 2</div>
    <div>Option 3</div>
    <div>Option 4</div>
    <div>Option 5</div>
  </div>
);

// If an option DIV is selected, prepend this as the first child inside it
const isSelectedOverlay = () => (
    <div>Selected (overlay)</div>
);
```

The issues I don't understand:

1. onClick of the option DIV, I need to set clicked element as the active item by adding a child inside that element (overlay div).  How do I store and manage which option div is the current selected element?
2. How do I manage state initially and onClick? Can I use a data-attr on the element itself and obtain that? Or do I call onClick with the option ID?

   3. How do I remove all other selected options and make this the selected option?
   4. I need the state to store the current selected option, but I'm not sure how to use that state to manage the selection itself.

I'd really appreciate help with this. I'm getting a bit stuck trying to work out the best way of doing it.

The UI looks like this:

[image: DIV as radio option in React]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barney, you should try declaring your component as a class so you can do state management with it. 
Check this docs for instructions on how to use state https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/components-props-and-state.html

Your component should have in the state a list of options and an index of which option is selected. Iterate through the list and do special treatment for the selected index. You can have each option be it's own component with and index that identifies it, a onChange callback funciton to set the state and a isSelected prop. If the prop is selected, you can add the "selected overlay" html to it.